# New tables within storage account after restarting function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have an Azure Function App with a setting AzureWebJobsStorage. There are 2 tables within the storage account. I want to stop Azure Function App, delete tables, restart Azure Function App so that new tables are created. I have the following code to restart function app:

> Restart-AzFunctionApp -Name "Function-App" -ResourceGroupName "Resource-Group" - Force

I don't see any tables being created in the storage account after restarting the function app. After refreshing the function app manually via Azure Portal, I see the tables being created. What am I missing? How do I get it working via PowerShell command?

Comment: Isn't simpler just to clear the tables instead of deleting and recreate them?

Comment: please provide your function code.

Comment: Is it possible to clear the tables via script?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get it working via PowerShell command?

Firstly, restarting the Azure Function App with PowerShell does not create tables automatically in the storage account.

The `AzureWebJobsStorage` you mentioned is the connection string used by functions to only interact with storage account with tables.

You need to delete the tables and then start/restart the function app. To delete the tables using PowerShell, there is a command called
[`Remove-azstoragetable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/remove-azstoragetable?view=azps-10.4.1) to be used.

```
$context= New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "newstj" -StorageAccountKey "xxx=="
Remove-AzStorageTable -Name "Instances" -Context $context
```

*Note:* If you have multiple tables, then use a `foreach` loop to traverse and delete all the ones.

*Now I can see nothing in the tables blade of my storage account.*

[image]

Once it is done, you can use `Start-AzFunctionApp` or `Restart-AzFunctionApp` to start the function app normally.

[image]

*Note:* If you are still concerned about the tables that are generated while reloading the `FunctionApp` manually, this could be due to the internal setup process when the Function App is accessed interactively.

If you're trying to do it with `PowerShell`, the above approach is probably the optimal way to proceed.

Comment: I already deleted the tables. But when I start the function app, I don't see any new tables.